# Javascript: Function with same name as variable value exists but receiving typeError, Why?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why I am getting `"Uncaught TypeError: ops is not a function"`while `ops` holds `multiply` so `ops()` resolves to `multiply()` and a function `multiply()` is defined in the scope.

```
var product = 1;
var sum = 0;
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter a No. ", 10)); 
var ops = prompt("Addition/ Multiplication", "multiply");
var y = x;

var operation_type = function (ops){
  var ops = ops;
  return ops;
}
var ops = operation_type(ops);
// console.log(ops);
console.log(ops(x));
// ops(x);

function addition (x) {
   for (i=0; i< x; i++) {
     sum = sum + y;
     y = y - 1;
   } 
   sum = "Recursive sum of " + x +  " is: " + sum; 
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = sum;
}

function multiply(x) {
   for (i=0; i< x; i++) {
    product = product*y;
    y = y - 1; 
   }
   product = "Recursive Product of " + x +  " is: " + product; 
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = product;
}
```

Thanks
bt

Comment: you are giving parameters in ops so it would be function. and ops function doesn't exist

Comment: `promt` only returns strings (or null), not functions. So clearly `ops` is not a function.

Comment: see the statment `var ops = operation_type(ops);` which means js fun `operation_type(ops)` will execute and return value to `ops` in very nex line you try to execute it as a function but `ops` is variable, not function thats why you are getting such error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var operation_type = function (ops){
  var ops = ops; // useless declaration/assignment
  return ops;    // return original argument value
}
var ops = operation_type(ops);
console.log(ops(x));
```

`operation_type` simply returned the value you passed in, a string, and assigned it to the `ops` variable. Doing `ops(x)` tries to call `ops`, a string, as a function. What you probably wanted to do was dynamically select the function that operates on `x`.

The `operation_type` function should probably return the actual function object. The function for the specified name can be resolved using the bracket notation (eg. `console.log(window[ops](x))`):

```
var operation_type = function (ops){
  return window[ops];
}
var ops = operation_type(ops);
console.log(ops(x));
```

Comment: You are correct, I wanted to dynamically select the function however I don't prefer using the global window object, is there any way the `window` object can be avoided or how would do the above problem if you wanted to dynamically select the function?

Comment: @bTech Attach your functions to the object, use that object instead of `window`.